# How to find a route between two geometries in PostGIS?

Tags: postgresql, gis, openstreetmap, postgis

I have imported some osm map data into my PostGIS database using `osm2pgsql`.

These are my tables:

[image]

What is the best way to find a route between 2 points in my PostGIS tables?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

To do route-finding in postGIS you need to download, install, and enable the [`pgrouting`](http://pgrouting.org) extension.

Once you have a `pgrouting` enabled extension, then you need to create your graph topology using the [`pgr_createTopology`](http://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/src/topology/doc/pgr_createTopology.html#pgr-create-topology) function, after which you can use route finding algorithms like [pgr_bdDijkstra](http://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/src/bd_dijkstra/doc/pgr_bdDijkstra.html#bd-dijkstra).

See this pgrouting [Getting Started](http://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/doc/src/tutorial/tutorial.html#tutorial) guide, as well as the [Routing Topology](http://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/doc/src/tutorial/topology.html#topology) page for a bit more context.